# MySQL SELECT Query where clause in a selection

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid, f.id as fave_id, f.user_id as user_id
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN job j 
ON p.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN favourites f
ON p.id = f.people_id
WHERE p.company_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

I have the above MySQL Query which works fine, the last two pieces of the selection are what I need to sort out though.

In each row by default they output `null` otherwise they output integers such as `fave_id` as `46` and `user_id` as `6`

What I actually need to figure out is if it is possible to output from the SELECT part of the query if both `fave_id` and `user_id` are not null in my head its something like this

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid, f.id as fave_id, f.user_id as user_id, [if fave_id && user_id then favorite = true] 
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN job j 
ON p.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN favourites f
ON p.id = f.people_id
WHERE p.company_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: user an `inner join` instead. `left` join selects all records from the "left" side of the query, and inserts nulls for any "right" side records where there's no match. `inner join` requires actual records be present on both sides.

Comment: @MarcB I need to pull all the rows out so I have to use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html) statement would work to check values and return a desired value:

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid, f.id as fave_id, f.user_id as user_id, 
    (CASE WHEN fave_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS favorite 
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN job j 
ON p.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN favourites f
ON p.id = f.people_id
WHERE p.company_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `and`:

```
fave_id is not null and user_id is not null
```